# On Premise deployment of Hyperledger Fabric without cloud

Tags: docker, kubernetes, deployment, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have created a PoC application using hyperledger fabric for three organizations.
Most of the content on internet is instructing to use cloud for the deployment of the solution.

- https://juarezjunior.medium.com/how-to-deploy-your-first-hyperledger-fabric-components-with-azure-kubernetes-service-aks-760563d9d543
- https://medium.com/google-cloud/fabric-on-google-cloud-platform-97525323457c
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ubrA3W1JMk0

1. If peers, orderers,ca server of all organizations are deployed in a
   cloud then how come hyperledger fabric is distribued?
2. Can this setup can be made in distributed , "in premise"
   infrastructure?
3. Is there any source for reference/links to do this sort of setup?

any suggestions/references will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> If peers, orderers,ca server of all organizations are deployed in a cloud then how come hyperledger fabric is distribued?

Each service (orderer, peer, etc) would be run on a different (virtual) machine within the same environment/cloud provider. Those machines could be distributed across various data-centers globally, or across different cloud providers, or even on many varying organisation's hardware. It makes relatively little difference, so long as they're not all on the same box, under the control of one organisation/person. Then it will be distributed.

> Can this setup can be made in distributed , "in premise" infrastructure?

Yes - it can be set up to run however you like, although you may run into access issues, from firewalls, etc. Perhaps you'd have different departments run their own peers within a single organisation across many offices.

> Is there any source for reference/links to do this sort of setup?

I believe most people start using the scripts from the hyperledger fabric codebase. Theres documentation here https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/build_network.html about spinning up the "build your first network" script - `byfn.sh` (looks like this may have been removed)

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples has a ci folder. Within it there's some steps to build/run/test the codebase examples. Eg.  https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/main/ci/scripts/run-test-network-basic.sh
calls  `network.sh` which is here: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/main/test-network/network.sh

If you really want to understand the necessary steps you'll need to work through it all. There's also some good documentation on what the various parts of the hyperledger-fabric system do here: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/345a08b5cd30ef937a8270d1722462e4cad1caa9/docs/source - you'll need to navigate through the directories to the parts you're interested in and locate the `.md` files which contain the documentation : eg.

- Peer [docs/source/peers/peers.md](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/345a08b5cd30ef937a8270d1722462e4cad1caa9/docs/source/peers/peers.md)
- Orderer [docs/source/orderer/ordering_service.md](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/345a08b5cd30ef937a8270d1722462e4cad1caa9/docs/source/orderer/ordering_service.md)
- Smart Contracts (aka Chaincode) - [docs/source/smartcontract/smartcontract.md](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/345a08b5cd30ef937a8270d1722462e4cad1caa9/docs/source/smartcontract/smartcontract.md)
- Channels - [docs/source/create_channel/channel_policies.md](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/345a08b5cd30ef937a8270d1722462e4cad1caa9/docs/source/create_channel/channel_policies.md)

You may also find some `Dockerfile`s in various repositories with different setups.

Comment: By reference/links  I meant, some example architecture/deployment, for a consortium of organizations, which are geographically distributed and cloud is not an option. @RobEvans if you could give any links/references of such deployment example, that would be really helpful.

Comment: Does this sort of thing help? https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/tutorial/commercial_paper.html

Comment: I have already  gone through the official documentation. These are design/implementation details.  I am looking for some example of deployment as per this (https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/deployment_guide_overview.html )  procedure.

Comment: https://www.hyperledger.org/learn/webinars/a-hitchhikers-guide-to-deploying-hyperledger-fabric-on-kubernetes This looks like the sort of thing you might be after - kubernetes definitions for the constituent parts (presumably they have a repo for this somewhere). To do on a commercial network, rather than public cloud, you just need to have clients enable kubernetes and share tls certs/endpoints

Comment: https://github.com/hyfen-nl/PIVT just came across this. Might also be relevant